# Primefaces TreeTable doesnt update when adding new items to it

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with updating a primefaces treetable. Editing the name of a node is no problem but when I add or delete an element, the treeview isn't updated.

The elementsTreeView.xhtml looks like this:

```
       <p:treeTable value="#{elementsTreeView.root}" var="node" dynamic="false" id="elements"
                     nodeVar="#{elementsTreeView.root}">
            <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{elementsTreeView.onNodeCollapse}" />
            <p:column headerText="#{labels['elements-tree-view.name']}"
                          sortBy="#{elementsTreeView.getCorrectNamingScheme(node)}" sortOrder="asc"
                          filterBy="#{elementsTreeView.getCorrectNamingScheme(node)}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                      selectionMode="single">
                <p:commandLink value="#{elementsTreeView.getCorrectNamingScheme(node)}"
                               action="#{elementsTreeView.navigateToEditElement(node)}"/>
                </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{labels['elements-tree-view.creation-date']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{node.creationDate.time}">
                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{labels['elements-tree-view.position-in-folder']}"
                      >
                <h:outputText value="#{elementsTreeView.determinePositionInFolder(node)}"
                              rendered="#{not elementsTreeView.isFolder(node)}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{labels['elements-tree-view.actions']}">
                <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-plus"
                                 action="#{elementsTreeView.navigateToCreateFolder(node)}"
                                 rendered="#{elementsTreeView.isFolder(node)}" styleClass="table-button rounded-button"
                                 value="#{labels['elements-tree-view.create-folder']}"/>
                <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-plus" action="#{elementsTreeView.navigateToCreateNote(node)}"
                                 rendered="#{elementsTreeView.isFolder(node)}" styleClass="table-button rounded-button"
                                 value="#{labels['elements-tree-view.create-note']}"/>
                <br/>
                <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-pencil" action="#{elementsTreeView.navigateToEditElement(node)}"
                                 styleClass="table-button rounded-button" update="@form"/>
                <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-trash" action="#{elementsTreeView.deleteElement(node)}"
                                 styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-danger" update="@form"
                                 rendered="#{elementsTreeView.isFolder(node)}">
                    <p:confirm header="#{labels['elements-tree-view.confirmation']}"
                               message="#{labels['elements-tree-view.confirm-delete-folder']}"
                               icon="pi pi-info-circle"/>
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-trash" action="#{elementsTreeView.deleteElement(node)}"
                                 styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-danger"
                                 rendered="#{not elementsTreeView.isFolder(node)}">
                    <p:confirm header="#{labels['elements-tree-view.confirmation']}"
                               message="#{labels['elements-tree-view.confirm-delete-note']}"
                               icon="pi pi-info-circle"/>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:treeTable>
```

The delete method looks like this. I even delete the element from the tree structure. It is still not changing:

```
public void deleteElement(final Element elementToBeRemoved){
    if(elementToBeRemoved instanceof Folder folder) {
        folderService.deleteFolder(folder);
    }
    else if (elementToBeRemoved instanceof Note note){
        noteService.deleteNote(note);
    }
    root.getChildren().removeIf(element->element.getData().equals(elementToBeRemoved));
    traverseTree(root, elementToBeRemoved);
}


public void traverseTree(final TreeNode tree, final Element elementToBeRemoved) {
    if(tree.getChildren().removeIf(element->element.getData().equals(elementToBeRemoved))){
        System.out.println("Entfernt");
        return;
    }
    for (final TreeNode child:tree.getChildren()){
        if (child.getData() instanceof Folder){
            traverseTree(child, elementToBeRemoved);
        }
    }
    initRoot();
}
```

If you need more code fragments, please take a look at my bitbucket public project.

Most important files:

- elementsTree(View)
- editNode(View)
- editFolder(View)

[1] Link to the project: https://bitbucket.org/Samuel19982/smartorganizr/src/master/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (which includes versions)

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to accomplish this? E.g. the user is involved in every action. I would have to rewrite the entire application.

Comment: So I tried to minimize it for the last couple hours. It is not possible. If I delete the user, the entire application collapses like a house of cards. As mentioned before the 3 files above are most relevant.

Comment: At least includes versions

Comment: What exactly are versions? What is a characteristic of a version? As I am new to stackoverflow I may not be up to date with the Stackoverflow nomenclature.

Comment: Versions of PrimeFaces and the JSF implementation you are using

Comment: Primefaces: 10.0.0                
Joinfaces Starter: 4.5.5

You can find the versions of every dependency in my pom.xml (It's a maven project).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your treeTable from the backend, by calling `PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:elements");` at the end of your deleteElement-method.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I added your line at the very end of the delete method. When deleting one of the elements in the tree, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

As primefaces offers a selection mode I found a temporary solution to select a Treenode and then delete it. The delete method looks like this:

```
public void deleteElement(){
    if(selectedTreeNode == null){
        JsfUtils.putErrorMessage(I18nExceptionUtils.getElementsTreeNoNodeSelected());
        return;
    }
    final Element elementToBeRemoved = (Element) selectedTreeNode.getData();
    handleDeletion(elementToBeRemoved);

    if(selectedTreeNode!=null) {
        selectedTreeNode.getParent().getChildren().remove(selectedTreeNode);
    }
}
```

where selectedTreeNode is the attribute in the Backend Bean.